# How do you change from Traditional form to Input form?

Tags: formatting, hold

I have something like this:

```
Hold[TraditionalForm[1/2 + x^2]]
```

And wish to change it to Input form with the use of code (that is, without clicking Cell > Convert To > InputForm)

Comment: If you look at Cell > Convert To > InputForm, it says right there the keyboard equivalent is shift-ctrl-i,  at least on windows.

Comment: Please read my question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

```
Block[{TraditionalForm},
  RawBoxes @ ToString[ Hold @ TraditionalForm[1/2 + x^2], InputForm]
]
```

[image]

It is even more strict as terms were not reordered as in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[TraditionalForm[1/2 + x^2]]][[1]]
```

Comment: It shows an Output form, that is 2D fraction instead of linear `1/2`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `ReleaseHold[Hold[TraditionalForm[1/2 + x^2]]][[1]] //  InputForm // Text` ok?

Comment: Ask OP, maybe, it is not the same thing as OP's case + ConvertTo InputForm